# Making a JButton stay depressed manually

Tags: java, jbutton

I would like to make a JButton stay pressed down and not be able to be pressed again until some event occurs is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: All my JButtons always look depressed :-(

Comment: I don't think I would be very happy if I was part of the swing API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you just want to disable the button? Try `setEnabled(false)` in your callback for the button.

Answer (score 7):

You should probably look at the JToggleButton class.  Associate it with an Action which calls setEnabled(false) to disable interaction.

Once your event happens you call setEnabled(true) and setSelected(false) to restore the original state of the button.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should have a look at the JButton Swing class [Here](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JToggleButton.html). It allows you to have a 2 state button, and so for what you need, you may just need to attach your button to some boolean, allowing it to be selected or not.